# How do I add transport headers to boto3 s3 client?

Tags: boto, boto3

I have looked at the docs but couldn't figure out how to add additional transport headers to boto3 s3 client or resource. I need to send Accept header. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify what is your objective/trying to achieve.

Comment: We have a custom application that works with S3. We cannot reach s3 directly and the custom application returns json instead of XML. So, in order to request the application to send XML response, I need to specify Accept=application/xml header. But I was not able to find either boto3 s3  api to handle json or pass this header. Hope this clarifies.